# Instanciation depending on type, generics, inheritance or both?

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance

I have a method instanciating a specific class depending on type send as parameter of this method. This works perfectly but I really don't like this `if(c == class_name.class)` way to deal with this and I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this using generics and inheritance. The method I use looks (maybe mistakenly...) dirty to me.

I followed several tutorials regarding generics and inheritance but even if I think I more or less understand these two concepts separately I'm strugling understanding the mix of both... And I think these both concepts could resolve my problem once mixed. Could anybody show me the right track to follow, generics, inheritance, both or keep my code like this. Is there a better way to do this ?

This is my actual method :

```
private void addData(String csvFile, char separator, Class<?> c) {
        int lineNumber = 1;
        CSVReader reader;

        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(csvFile)), separator);
            String[] line;

            realm.beginTransaction();
            if(c == FlagDef.class) {
                while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    FlagDef flagDef = new FlagDef(Long.parseLong(line[0]), line[1], line[2]);
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s %s", line[0], line[1], line[2]));
                    realm.copyToRealm(flagDef);
                    lineNumber++;
                }
            }
            if(c == Picture.class) {
                while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    Picture picture = new Picture(Long.parseLong(line[0]), line[1]);
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s", line[0], line[1]));
                    realm.copyToRealm(picture);
                    lineNumber++;
                }
            }
            realm.commitTransaction();

            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("File %s not found : %s", csvFile, ex));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error parsing line number %s : %s", lineNumber, ex));
        }
    }
```

The calls to this method :

```
addData(FILE_FLAGS,SEPARATOR,FlagDef.class);
addData(FILE_PICTURES,SEPARATOR,Picture.class);
```

The declaration of `copyToRealm` method can be found [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/Realm.java#L992)

This is for Android and I'm actually targeting API 16.

I only indicates two types `Picture` and `FlagDef` for brevity here but I'm planning to have at least 10 different types.

Comment: that sounds like impossible, your types(classes) are known at runtime, and at that point there is not type `T` (or whatever generic you have). passing a `Class<T>` seems like the correct thing here and not dirty at all to me

Comment: In your case, I don't think there's another solution to avoid `if(c == class_name.class)` since you can't determine the type of the object with your CSV file. However, your problem looks like a [Strategy Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) problem IMO.

Comment: How do you get the value of `c` when you call addData?

Comment: @StephaneM I just edited my question. The context here is I just have several csv files with data I need to put in a Realm database. So I know which class to send as parameter since each file correspond to a specific class mapped to my Realm database objects.

Comment: Generics won't help you here. They are a compile-time only construct.

Comment: Please add the declaration of the `copyToRealm` method to your question.

Comment: @VGR https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/Realm.java#L992

Comment: @MickaëlB Thank you for your comment, I'm actually having a look at this Strategy pattern since I'll have more than 10 different types in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had several answers to my question.

I think the solution from @VGR is a good one. But the problem with it is that my project targets Android API 16. So in my case the functional solution proposed by @VGR can't be used because [Function was only introduced since API 24](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Function.html). Therefore maybe this solution lack of flexibility for future evolutions. Anyway functionnal programming is not my best skills for now so difficult to judge about it.

The solution proposed by StephaneM is a good one but as I got it it needs a modification and can't be generalized.

@Eugene and @mickaël-b proposed in comments to use the [Strategy Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This is the solution I finally choiced. Thank you all for your answers and comments, it was immensely helpful :)

[image]

See below the working code, feel free to comment if I can make it better in any way. Or if I made some mistakes... Again I'm only using 2 classes so 2 strategies for brevity here but in the end I'll have more than ten strategies.

For those interested this code can be used to generate Realm database from csv files.

```
RealmDbGenerator dbGenerator = new RealmDbGenerator(this);    

    //flags
    dbGenerator.setGenerationStrategy(new FlagDefStrategy());
    dbGenerator.addData(FILE_FLAGS,SEPARATOR);

    //pictures
    dbGenerator.setGenerationStrategy(new PictureStrategy());
    dbGenerator.addData(FILE_PICTURES,SEPARATOR);
```

RealDbGenerator :

```
public class RealmDbGenerator {
    private static final String TAG = RealmDbGenerator.class.getSimpleName();

    public void setGenerationStrategy(GenerationStrategy generationStrategy) {
        this.generationStrategy = generationStrategy;
    }

    private GenerationStrategy generationStrategy;
    private Realm realm;
    private Context context;

    public RealmDbGenerator(Context context) {
        this.realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addData(String csvFile, char separator) {
        CSVReader reader;

        int lineNumber = 1;

        try {
                reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(csvFile)), separator);
                String[] line;

                realm.beginTransaction();
                while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    generationStrategy.addData(line, realm);
                }
                realm.commitTransaction();

                reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("File %s not found : %s", csvFile, ex));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error parsing line number %s : %s", lineNumber, ex));
        }
    }
}
```

Strategies interface :

```
public interface GenerationStrategy {
    void addData(String[] line, Realm realm);
}
```

FlagDefStrategy :

```
public class FlagDefStrategy implements GenerationStrategy {
    private static final String TAG = FlagDefStrategy.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void addData(String[] line, Realm realm) {
        FlagDef flagDef = new FlagDef(Long.parseLong(line[0]), line[1], line[2]);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s %s", line[0], line[1], line[2]));
        realm.copyToRealm(flagDef);
    }
}
```

PictureStrategy :

```
public class PictureStrategy implements GenerationStrategy  {
    private static final String TAG = FlagDefStrategy.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void addData(String[] line, Realm realm) {
        Picture picture = new Picture(Long.parseLong(line[0]), line[1]);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s", line[0], line[1]));
        realm.copyToRealm(picture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the notion of type erasure, where at runtime, the generics will be erased. What you have right now is considered "clean" and used quite a lot for such cases.

The only thing I could suggest is having your `Picture` and `FlagDef` could implement a marker interface for example, like `CSVable` (yeah, really bad name) and change your method to :

```
<T extends CSV> void addData(Class<T> c)
```

so that your types are filtered at compile time (you can only pass an object that implements `CSVable`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like this. Still just hesitating to leave my code like this adding this marker interface or choice StephaneM answer.

Comment: @Laurent if you ever plan to have more then two types a strategy pattern is more correct, *especially* if you might have duplicate code used in multiple cases.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene , I'm having a look at this [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) . I'm actually planning to have more than 10 different types.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Class<?> c` argument to `Function<String[], RealmModel>`:

```
private void addData(String csvFile, char separator, Function<String[], RealmModel> modelConstructor) {
```

And instead of all those `if` blocks, you can just have one:

```
while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    RealmModel model = modelConstructor.apply(line);
    Log.d(TAG, String.join(" ", line));
    realm.copyToRealm(model);
    lineNumber++;
}
```

Calls to your addData method would look like this:

```
addData(FILE_FLAGS, SEPARATOR, line -> new FlagDef(Long.parseLong(line[0]), line[1], line[2]));
addData(FILE_PICTURES, SEPARATOR, line -> new Picture(Long.parseLong(line[0]), line[1]));
```

Comment: I love this ! just trying to fully understand it :)

Comment: I must admit this is a very smart solution !!! Unfortunately I should have put more details in my question. This is for Android and [Function](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Function.html) has only been added since API 24. I can't target API 24 since it's only [20% market devices](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)... But thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a builder class that will create an object reading a line:

```
abstract class Builder<T> {
    abstract T build( String[] line);
}
```

With 2 implementations:

```
class FlagDefBuilder extends Builder<FlagDef > {

    @Override
    FlagDef build( String[] line )
    {
        FlagDef flagDef = new FlagDef(Long.parseLong(line[0]), line[1], line[2]);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s %s", line[0], line[1], line[2]));
        return flagDef;
    } 

}

    class PictureBuilder extends Builder<FlagDef > {

        @Override
        FlagDef build( String[] line )
        {
            Picture picture = new Picture(Long.parseLong(line[0]), line[1]);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s", line[0], line[1]));
            return picture;
        }       
    }
```

Then addData will be like this:

```
    private void addData(String csvFile, char separator, Builder<?> b) {
        int lineNumber = 1;
        CSVReader reader;

        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(csvFile)), separator);
            String[] line;

            realm.beginTransaction();
                while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    realm.copyToRealm(b.build(line));
                    lineNumber++;
                }
            }
            realm.commitTransaction();

            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("File %s not found : %s", csvFile, ex));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Error parsing line number %s : %s", lineNumber, ex));
        }
    }
```

And you can invoke it this way:

```
addData(FILE_FLAGS,SEPARATOR, new FlagDefBuilder());
addData(FILE_PICTURES,SEPARATOR, new PictureBuilder());
```

You can add a third builder type without modifying addData.

Comment: Note: I don't know why i created an abstract class and not an interface.

Comment: I like your approach. But I'm not sure to adopt it since several people told me my solution is not dirty. Yours looks nice but in the end it introduces more verbosity and "complexity". But yes I like it, I'm just not sure wanting to make my code more complex just for it looks nicer to my eyes if my first code is a good solution. Anyway I'll not forget to accept your answer if I choice it in the end, still not sure. Thank you.

Comment: This will only work if `copyToRealm` parameter is of type `Object` (it isn't). For this case it can be fixed by making `addData` generic and bounded by `RealmModel` but this is not a good general solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a modularity problem, why don't create two methods for adding data and avoid the class type parameter?

```
private void addFlagData(String csvFile, char separator) {
...
}

private void addPictureData(String csvFile, char separator) {
...
}
```

Comment: in such a case, better to use the strategy pattern like in the comments to the question

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't agree. I actually put only two cases, Flag and Picture for brevity here. But at the end i'll have more than 10 methods. I can't write 10 times the same methods this would look still more than dirty to me :) and even for 2 cases I'm not a fan of code replication.